# Custom report type is missing

Tags: custom-report-type

We have few reports based on one custom report type (e;g efforts with case)
but weird part is when i try to edit this custom report type; it is not showing up...

but I am able to create reports of this custom report type... (This custom report type is listed under "Others" folder)

Has anyone come across this issue before and what is the fix for it so that we can edit this custom report type..

Comment: what is the name of the custom report type, administrative report types are listed under others too,you cannot access them when creating your custom report.

Comment: The report type is "Efforts with Case". I can select this report type while creating new reports, but cannot find this report type to edit (I am trying to add some fields to this custom report type); this custom report type was under "Others"

Comment: Did you create this Report type yourself? I mean to say are you sure it's a custom report type?

Comment: I do not think "Efforts with case" is a admin report, as CoryCowgill suggested check if you can manage custom report types.

Comment: It could be that the report is restricted. Edit the report folder that the report is under and see if there's restriction.

Answer (score 2):

Does your profile have the "Manage Custom Report" types permission? You will need that to edit the Report Type. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this happen before - the most difficult to discover was:

The report was built as a special request by Salesforce.com, in which case it will not be accessible to you, even if you are the Sys Admin.  We had them build a report type for us so that we could report on quote approvals. Approvals are not something that you can report on as a standard record. They built the report type, and we could run reports using it, but it wasn't in the list of reports that could be modified.

Check with support to see if this is the case.